# How to enable remote login?

Tags: ssh, login, authentication

Currently I can only login to my remote linux via the "ubuntu" user account, without a password (via SSH authentication). I have another user configured on the machine, and if I try to login with its username + password I get

> Disconnected: No supported
>   authentication methods available

How do I configure this user to accept user/pass authentication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that your sshd is configured to allow access via public key authentication and to disallow access via password.

There are a couple of things that you can do. The better option is to generate a key-pair for the new account and to copy the public key to your remote host's "~/.ssh/authorized_keys" file. You can use ssh-keygen, puttygen, etc. to generate the keys.

Alternatively, you can enable sshd password authentication. Edit the "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" file and ensure that the "PasswordAuthentication" directive is set to yes:

```
PasswordAuthentication  yes
```

Save the file, restart sshd (e.g. with `systemctl restart ssh` on systemd-based systems) and you should then be able to use passwords.

Comment: I'd like to use mRemote as my SSH client, and as far as I can tell, it doesn't support authentication based on key-pairs. This is why I wanted to setup user/pass authentication.

Comment: I have mRemote configured to use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) as the ssh client. This then allows me to use Pageant to store the keys and login using them.

Comment: Cool. Now a followup: http://superuser.com/questions/248091/how-to-ingerate-mremote-and-putty-pageant

Answer (score 1):

In first-time Linux user 
 edit the sshd_config file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Then you have to find

```
# PermitRootLogin no
```

you have to remove the # and change it to yes

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Ok now save it

```
ctrl + x
```

then

```
Y - yes
```

all the changes will be saved now not only that now you have to restart the service

```
service sshd restart
```

Ok, check now you can connect through the ssh.

Comment: Explicitly adding root login to sshd has nothing to do with this particular question, and would add unnecessary risk if a person was to do this in an attempt to solve the problem (by allowing remote root login attempts where they were previously disallowed).

Comment: Thank you @Jeff Schaller is there any other way to the selected user?

Comment: Notice that this particular question [has an accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7702/117549); it appears that their configuration was not allowing password authentication as a method.